# Using boostrap in django template correctly

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have this hierarchical order of models: courses, study programmes, departments and faculties. I have 2 columns in bootstrap. The first column lists all faculties, with their specific departments and the study programmes of each department. The second column lists all courses. I want that when someone clicks on a faculty, to display the specific courses for that faculty in the second column by replacing all courses, same for departments or study programmes. Now, I tried something, but I don't know how to achieve this result. I don't know how to list courses for each faculty, as you can notice, I put faculties.0 as a test.

```html
<script>
        $('#btnClick').on('click', function () {
            if ($('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
                $('#2').show().siblings('div').hide();
            } else if ($('#2').css('display') != 'none') {
                $('#1').show().siblings('div').hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h4>Search courses</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <br>
                    <ul>
                        {% for faculty in faculties %}
                            <li id="btnClick">{{ faculty.name }}</li>
                            <ul>
                                {% for department in departments %}
                                    {% if department.faculty == faculty %}
                                        <li>{{ department.name }}</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            {% for study in studies %}
                                                {% if study.department == department %}
                                                    <li>{{ study.name }}</li>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div id="1">
                        <h3>All courses</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {% for course in courses %}
                                <li>
                                    <a id="first" href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a>
                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="2" style="display:none;">
                        <h3> {{ faculties.0 }} courses</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {% for course in courses %}
                                <li>
                                    <a id="first" href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a>
                                    <p>chinchin</p>
                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is how it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEpq9.png

Comment: try to work with classes than id´s , you generate the same id´s in the loops wich is invalid and may lead to errors (an id should occur only once)

Comment: @johnSmith Did that. Now what's next ?

Comment: You are using the exact same `for course in courses` loop in both instances, without, as far as I can tell, changing what `courses` represents. How are you expecting it to know which courses belong to the specific faculty?

Comment: @PerlPingu Yes, thats what Im struggling with. What should I do ?

Comment: Well it would help if you provided the actual structure of your models, or at least the foreign key/relationship fields which connect them.

Comment: Here they are: https://pastebin.com/uc3wRLq0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think part of your problem is that you want a second, hidden div, with Faculty specific courses listed, however your current HTML template is only ever going to give you one hidden div, with a single faculties courses in. You need to have one hidden div per faculty.

**NB**: I wouldn't do it this way using hidden divs, personally I'd use Bootstrap's [tab/pill style](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp).

Anyway, I think the below should give you the sort of result you are looking for. Obviously I can't test it with your models. I've changed the template to use the [related objects notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/) rather than your `if ==` style.

I've also changed the jQuery a bit. Hopefully it's ok, although it will have the effect that the `#1` div will only be visible before any links are clicked.

**UPDATED**: I had missed the `{{ }}` around the `faculty.name` in the div id's and I also hadn't wrapped the jQuery script in a `$(document).ready()` or included the jQuery cdn. It should work as intended now.

**UPDATED 2**: Changed the `id` of elements to use the `faculty.pk` which should be a number and avoid any issues with spaces.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnClick').on('click', function() {
        var faculty_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+faculty_id+'_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
    })
})
</script>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h4>Search courses</h4>
            <hr>
            <br>
            <ul>
                {% for faculty in faculties %}
                    <li class="btnClick" id="fac_{{ faculty.pk }}">{{ faculty.name }}</li>
                    <ul>
                        {% for department in faculty.department_set.all %}
                            <li>{{ department.name }}</li>
                            <ul>
                                {% for study in department.study_set.all %}
                                    <li>{{ study.name }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div id="1">
                <h3>All courses</h3>
                <ul>
                    {% for course in courses %}
                        <li>
                            <a class="first" href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            {% for faculty in faculties %}
            <div id="fac_{{ faculty.pk }}_tab" style="display:none;">
                <h3> {{ faculty.name }} courses</h3>
                <ul>
                    {% for department in faculty.department_set.all %}
                    {% for study in department.study_set.all %}
                    {% for course in study.study_set.all %}
                        <li>
                            <a class="first" href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a>
                            <p>chinchin</p>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this reponse. Although, I think the script is not good anymore. Has no effect.

Comment: I will try and test it and fix it

Comment: you forgot to close the for in the first  {% for faculty in faculties %}. But anyway, the problem is the same. Script does nothing. Thanks for trying to help me..

Comment: Ok, I just realised your faculty names almost certainly contain spaces which aren't allowed in html `id` elements. Hopefully my latest edit fixes everything.

Comment: That’s what should be showing when you click on the Faculty link? Is it showing all courses?

Comment: I did some tweaks on the code.It was my bad. Everything working properly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164987/discussion-between-dann-m-and-perlpingu).